# Handle Turkish uppercase and lowercase correctly, need to modify/override built-in functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, built-in, cyrillic, turkish

I am working with multilingual text data, among others with Russian using the Cyrillic alphabet and Turkish. I basically have to compare the words in two files `my_file` and `check_file` and if the words in `my_file` can be found in `check_file`, write them in an output file keeping the meta-information about these words from both input files.

Some words are lowercased while other words are capitalised so I have to lowercase all the words to compare them. As I use Python 3.6.5 and Python 3 uses unicode as default, it handles lowercasing and later on capitalising the words correctly for Cyrillic. For Turkish however, some letters are not handled correctly. Uppercase `'İ'` should correspond to lowercase `'i'`, uppercase `'I'` should correspond to lowercase `'ı'` and lowercase `'i'` should correspond to uppercase `'İ'` which is not the case if I type the following in the console:

```
>>> print('İ'.lower())
i̇  # somewhat not rendered correctly, corresponds to unicode 'i\u0307'
>>> print('I'.lower())
i
>>> print('i'.upper())
I
```

I am doing as follows (simplified sample code):

```
# python my_file check_file language

import sys

language = sys.argv[3]

# code to get the files as lists

my_file_list = [['ıspanak', 'N'], ['ısır', 'N'], ['acık', 'V']]
check_file_list = [['109', 'Ispanak', 'food_drink'], ['470', 'Isır', 'action_words'], [409, 'Acık', 'action_words']]

# get the lists as dict
my_dict = {}
check_dict = {}

for l in my_file_list:
    word = l[0].lower()
    pos = l[1]
    my_dict[word] = pos

for l in check_file_list:
    word_id = l[0]
    word = l[1].lower()
    word_cat = l[2]
    check_dict[word] = [word_id, word_cat]

# compare the two dicts
for word, pos in my_dict.items():
    if word in check_dict:
        word_id = check_dict[word][0]
        word_cat = check_dict[word][1]
        print(word, pos, word_id, word_cat)
```

This gives me only one result but it should give me the three words as result:

```
acık V 409 action_words
```

What I've done so far based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703106/python-and-turkish-capitalization?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa):

1. Read the accepted answer which proposes to use [PyICU](https://pypi.org/project/PyICU/) but I want my code to be useable without people having to install stuff so I didn't implement it.
2. Tried to `import locale` and `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8')` as mentionned in the question but it didn't change anything.
3. Implement two functions `turkish_lower(self)` and `turkish_upper(self)` for the three problematic letters as described in the second answer which seems to be the only solution:

   ```
   def turkish_lower(self):
       self = re.sub(r'İ', 'i', self)
       self = re.sub(r'I', 'ı', self)
       self = self.lower()
       return self

   def turkish_upper(self):
       self = re.sub(r'i', 'İ', self)
       self = self.upper()
       return self
   ```

But how can I use these two functions without having to check `if language == 'Turkish'` every time? Should I override the built-in functions `lower()` and `upper()`? If yes, what is the pythonic way of doing it? Should I implement classes for the various languages I'm working with and override the built-in functions inside the class for Turkish?

Comment: implement `to_lower` and `to_upper` methods and language as parameter. Best way is using `icu`, dependencies are inevitable

Comment: Could you possibly clarify how to do so? My goal is to be able to use `word = word.lower()` without having to clarify `if language == 'Turkish: word = turkish_lower(word[0])+word[1:] else word = word.lower()` in every for loops I'm using

Comment: python does not support extension as swift. If you want to use `lower()`, you have to create your own type (class) and check language. In every case you have O(n) complexity, so choose one way

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703106/python-and-turkish-capitalization

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple "language aware" string that subclasses `str` and will do the proper uppercasing and lowercasing, for example:

```py
class LanguageAwareStr(str):
    lang = None


class RussianStr(LanguageAwareStr):
    lang = 'ru'


class TurkishStr(LanguageAwareStr):
    lang = 'tr'

    _case_lookup_upper = {'İ': 'i', 'I': 'ı'}  # lookup uppercase letters
    _case_lookup_lower = {v: k for (k, v) in _case_lookup_upper.items()}

    # here we override the lower() and upper() methods
    def lower(self):
        chars = [self._case_lookup_upper.get(c, c) for c in self]
        result = ''.join(chars).lower()
        cls = type(self)  # so we return a TurkishStr result
        return cls(result)

    def upper(self):
        chars = [self._case_lookup_lower.get(c, c) for c in self]
        result = ''.join(chars).upper()
        cls = type(self)  # so we return a TurkishStr result
        return cls(result)
```

Then when you read a string, knowing what language it is, you wrap it in the proper LanguageAwareStr subclass, and then just use it regularly:

```py
from langaware import RussianStr, TurkishStr
```

```py
if language == 'turkish':
    LangStr = TurkishStr  # can also create a dict to lookup the correct class
```

Then when you read language strings, you simply wrap them in a call to `LangStr()`:

```py
for l in my_file_list:
    word = LangStr(l[0]).lower()
    pos = l[1]
    my_dict[word] = pos

for l in check_file_list:
    word_id = l[0]
    word = LangStr(l[1]).lower()
    word_cat = l[2]
    check_dict[word] = [word_id, word_cat]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying install the turkish language pack for locale:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-tr
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales  # *
```

You can also check which languages you have in locale using the terminal command: `$ locale -a`

https://forum.yazbel.com/t/cozuldu-locale-setlocale-locale-lc-all-tr-tr-yapisinda-sorun-yasiyorum-turkce-karakter-sorunu/476